# How can I make this integer public in Java?

Tags: java

I want to make the integer N public so that I can use it in other classes.

```
public Board() {
    this(2);
}

public Board(int n) {

    do {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Minimum 1 players and Maximum 4 players.");
        System.out.print("How many players? ");
        n = scan.nextInt();
    }while(n > 4 || n < 1);

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.getContentPane().add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(640, 520);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    new Thread(this).start();
    // r.start();

    pieces = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pieces[i] = 1;

    dice = new Dice(this);
}
```

I've tried many thing to try and make N public, but none of them have worked.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Scary Wombat - yes?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please include the code you have tried so far to solve this problem so we can help you debug or improve it.

Comment: just declare it as public

Comment: Why are you taking `n` as a parameter when you just go to overwrite it in your loop?

Answer (score 2):

Create a member and access it using getter

```
public class Board {
    private int n;

    public Board(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        //...
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright I've done this, now how would I call this in another class?

Comment: @Reilley You created instance of board in another class, something like `Board board = new Board(2);`. Now you can do `int n = board.getN();`

Answer (score 0):

Write class and add variable Integer marked as public. public means it can be accessible from any class.

```
class Example {
public Integer myValue;


}
```

But better way is to use getter and setter for your variable and mark variable as private

```
class Example {
private Integer myValue;

public Integer getMyValue(){
return myValue;
}
public void setMyValue(Integer myValue){
this.myValue=myValue;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delcare the integer as public in the class. Or even static public.

```
class X {
  public int dice = 0;
  public static int DICE = 1;
  public int getDice(){return dice; }
  public static int getDICE(){return DICE; }
}

class Y {
 void x() {
   int v = X.DICE; // via static filed
   int w = new X().dice; // via public field
   int x = new X().getDice(); // via public Method
   int a = X.getDICE(); // via static method
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, and you need to introduce a member variable. Member variables in Java should not be made public (C# differs slightly). In Java you make member variables non public and expose them via getter methods. I understand in your question that 'n' represents the number of players so I created the 'numPlayers' member variable and added a 'getNumPlayers()' method.

As you have two constructors with mostly the same initialization code, I created an init() method for the constructors to share. The constructor without the argument defaults to 2 players. The constructor with the argument allows you to nominate the number of players, but if not providing a number of players between 1 and 4, then it keeps asking you for a new number of players.

Please review this answer and see if it meets your requirements.

```
public class Board {

   private int numPlayers;


   public Board(int n) {
       while (n < 1 || n > 4) {
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Minimum 1 players and Maximum 4 players.");
           System.out.print("How many players? ");
           n = scan.nextInt();
       }
       init(n);
   }


   public Board() {
      init(2);
   }


   public int getNumPlayers() {
      return this.numPlayers;
   }

   private init(int n) {
       this.numPlayers = n;
       Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
       contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

       frame.getContentPane().add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setSize(640, 520);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       new Thread(this).start();
       // r.start();

       pieces = new int[n];
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           pieces[i] = 1;

       dice = new Dice(this);
   }
}
```

Chris